# Create a computed observable for formatted values for a bunch of variables

Tags: knockout.js, formatted, computed-observable

I have 3 observable variables in view-model, and want to output to formatted value. However, I don't want to write computed method for each of them since they are identical. What is the best way to reuse the code? Thanks.

The code I am going to achieve is:

```
   this.formattedPrice = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return '$' + this.price().toFixed(2);
        },
        write: function (value) {
            // Strip out unwanted characters, parse as float, then write the raw data back to the underlying "price" observable
            value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
            this.price(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value); // Write to underlying storage
        },
        owner: this
    });
```

And the failed example is in: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBxy4/68/)

Thanks,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are a couple ways that you can make this reusable.

If you want to handle this in your view model, then a good choice is to create an extension that will store the formatted computed observable as a "sub-observable" of your original.  You can extend observables using [extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) or by adding to the shared `fn` object as described [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html).  I prefer the latter.

So, you could add a function to observables called `withCurrencyFormat`.  It might look like:

```
ko.observable.fn.withCurrencyFormat = function(precision) {
    var observable = this;
    observable.formatted = ko.computed({
        read: function (key) {
            return '$' + (+observable()).toFixed(precision);
        },
        write: function (value) {
            value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
            observable(isNaN(value) ? null : value); // Write to underlying storage 
        }        
    }); 

    return observable;
};
```

Now, you can say:

```
 self.week1Amount = ko.observable(w1).withCurrencyFormat(2);
 self.week2Amount = ko.observable(w2).withCurrencyFormat(2);
 self.week3Amount = ko.observable(w3).withCurrencyFormat(2);
```

and bind against it in the UI like:

```
    <td><input data-bind="value: week1Amount.formatted" /></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: week2Amount.formatted" /></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: week3Amount.formatted" /></td>
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/xskJN/

Another choice is to move this into a binding, so you can leave your view model alone. This would use similar code, but in a custom binding handler that might look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.valueAsCurrency = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor(),
            formatted = ko.computed({
                read: function (key) {
                    return '$' + (+observable()).toFixed(2);
                },
                write: function (value) {
                    value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
                    observable(isNaN(value) ? null : value); // Write to underlying storage 
                },
                disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element                
            });

        //apply the actual value binding with our new computed
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: formatted });
    }        
};
```

So, in the binding handler we are create our computed and then using the `value` binding against it.

Now, your view model would need no changes and you would bind in the UI like:

```
    <td><input data-bind="valueAsCurrency: week1Amount" /></td>
    <td><input data-bind="valueAsCurrency: week2Amount" /></td>
    <td><input data-bind="valueAsCurrency: week3Amount" /></td>
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/sD6y4/

Comment: I have another question, how to apply this to the sum field, which is read-only. Again, my not working code is http://jsfiddle.net/sD6y4/4/. Since I have sum1, sum2, ..., fields. Is it possible to make a reusable function in this case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could add a `textAsCurrency` binding that just does the `read` part and applies the `text` binding.  Might look like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/3nrKD/

Comment: Cool way. I didn't know there are so many ways to solve it. Now I have another question: After updating the model from server via ajax, UI was not refreshed. I guess it is because I am using an array. The example is http://jsfiddle.net/3nrKD/1/. Is it possible to make it work? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. I found the issue, and made it works here, http://jsfiddle.net/3nrKD/3/. Thanks.

Comment: Hi RP. I found an example, like http://jsfiddle.net/3nrKD/5/. So my understanding is that if you update the observable variable, week1Amount, then the UI would be updated. But if you create a new one. It doesn't change. Is my understanding right? Thanks.

Comment: This is great, however neither method appears to update the UI if the user changes the value such that the underlying value is the same. e.g. change $10.00 to $10 and it won't be updated back to $10.00. Is there a way around that? I can ask as a separate question if you'd prefer