# knockoutjs format numbers with commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm new to knockout and just starting to get my head around the framework. However, I've come into a problem whereby I'm trying to format large numbers with commas. I've been able to get the number to format to decimal places using the extenders API but this isn't what I want.

The number is stored in an array and an example of a number used in the app will be 5 million. So I need the values to print out 5,000,000 - is this possible? I'm guessing it has to be.

Comment: So basically you're looking for a javascript function to convert 5000000 into 5,000,000?

Comment: Yes but it has to be compatible with knockout and binds to the data it's formatting so it updates in real-time & keeps the comma separated structure.

Comment: How do you interact with the data? Do you change the value in some place and need a text field to update with the converted value? Or is it in the same place (an input text tag)?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Comment: Yeah, the value gets changed elsewhere and the text that gets output needs to update with the converted value + comma separated structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [create an computed observable for formatted values for a bunch of variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996635/create-an-computed-observable-for-formatted-values-for-a-bunch-of-variables)

Comment: No because if you read it carefully, you'd see that it just adds decimal places with no comma-separation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the formatting, you can use the following regex (warning: it does not work with float): `mystring.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')`

You can check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/XgezN/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to create a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).  The easiest thing would probably be to use an [existing jQuery formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990512/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits-using-jquery) to format the display when the observable changes and then set up an event handler for the textbox to [parse the textbox (removing the commas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832829/numbers-with-commas-in-javascript) when the users types something new.